# Sugestions on How to start an APP with OCR, for personal use only

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

First off: I Only know the basics, so please do bear with me on this one, thank you!

So, I have an idea that, in the paper, seems not to difficult to pull off.

Were I work, whenever you do a Clock in/out, the machines issue an paper with the Work adress stuff, your name, date, time and, as I presume, the data registration code.

And what I exactly want with this OCR app is just to extract the Date, time and data code, then save the picture AND put it on some sort of database (Also if It could be on a google/One drive account, it would be nice).

That is it. The research that i have done so far.... Maybe the Tessaract OCR could prove to be the way.

Ideas and sugestions would be greatly welcome. Thx in advance.